# Webpack generates a hash in GET parameter - how to remove it?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I have preloaded the font files at the header tag:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_resources/themes/app/dist/fonts/proxima-nova-bold.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin/>
<link rel="preload" href="/_resources/themes/app/dist/fonts/proxima-nova-regular.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin/>
<link rel="preload" href="/_resources/themes/app/dist/fonts/proxima-nova-semibold.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin/>
```

its shown me these warnings in the console on Chrome browser.

> The resource {URL} was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Console:

[image: Chrome console warnings]

I have figured out this causes from Webpack is generate hash in get parameter. I use laravel.mix.js to compile the assets and resources for my PHP project.

Network:

[image: Chrome: network resources]

How can I config the webpack.mix.js to remove hash in GET parameter for file type **woff2, woff, and eot**? The other file types still remaining the same.